# How to confirm which path aws cli referring to as dependent library in linux?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Hi I was trying to access aws using [aws-okta-processor](https://github.com/godaddy/aws-okta-processor).
Following the instruction(pip install aws-okta-processor) and ran below code.

```
sudo aws sts get-caller-identity
```

However, I got following error.

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'aws-okta-processor'
```

I suspect that even though I set up the virtual environment with aws-okta-processor, aws cli command is referring to deferent folder as dependent library.

Can anyone tell me how to know where aws cli is referring to and how to fix it?

Comment: The authors of that module recommend using [pipx](https://pypi.org/project/pipx/) to avoid potential problems with executable paths and dependency isolation. Do you have the executable in your PATH (can you run `aws-okta-processor`?)

Comment: So, you installed as a non-root user and are now using sudo to run as root? Did you try `sudo -s`? That said, do you even need to run this as root?

Comment: @jarmod I get following message when I type sudo -s aws sts get-caller-identity.   
    
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Comment: Your credentials were presumably stored as your default, non-root user (ec2-user or ubuntu, for example). So once you've sudo'd to root, they are no longer the current user's credentials (because the current user in that context is root). Why even use sudo? Do you need to?

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar problem in mac though, both aws and aws-cli were installed in the `python bin` directory -> `/Users/rk/Library/Python/3.9/bin/aws` and `/Users/rk/Library/Python/3.9/bin/aws-okta-processor` which is of course not accessible from anywhere

**Solution**

1. `brew install awscli`
2. Install `aws-okta-processor`
   using [pip**x**](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/) NOT pip, it does help in creating in executables like *aws-okta-processor* in `~/.local/bin/`, which is accessible from anywhere. Restart the terminal to execute

   aws sts get-caller-identity